# How to summarize if all count equals zero from multiple csv files?

Tags: python

I have several csv files that I process each day from a single folder, but for this problem I'm just using a sample of 3 csv's. What my output is, is to read each csv and extract a count of the word "Unknown" from each csv if it is present and get the name of the associated csv.  I have a script that does this, but in addition to this, I would like to have the opposite.  In the case where there are no "Unknown" (word) found in any of the csv files, I would like a single print statement saying "All files are ready to go!".  I am using Python 3.6.  Here is what I have, and what does not work in the script.  To clarify, the "Unknown" is a word that is manually typed into the csv document in column 9.

Sample files are:

a_csv.csv, b_csv.csv, c_csv.csv

```python
    import glob     
    target_dir = r'C:\\data\\...'
        
    for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
        with open(file) as f:
            content = f.read()
            
            # Get the count of each "Unknown" from each file
            count = content.count('Unknown')
        
            # Print file name with count of "Unknown" and omitting the .csv from name
            if count != 0:
                print('\n, file[:-4] + ":" + str(count))
        
            # HERE'S what does not work how I want
            elif count == 0:
                print('\nAll files are ready to go!")
```

Here's my output, if "Unknown" is present with current code.

All files are ready to go!

b_csv: 5

All files are ready to go!

The script prints "All files are ready to go!" for each file that passed the count == 0 test.  I get this process, but how do I tune it in to printing the statement just once for all files if there is no "Unknown" at all in the files?

Desired output if there are no "Unknown" detected in any of the files, printed just once.

All files are ready to go!

Any help/suggestions for solving this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to track the total amount of `Unkown`s.
As you only want to print it once, you should avoid printing in the for-loop.
This would lead to, as you already noticed, multiple outputs.

```py
import glob     
target_dir = r'C:\\data\\...'

total_count = 0
for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
with open(file) as f:
    content = f.read()
    
    # Get the count of each "Unknown" from each file
    count = content.count('Unknown')
    total_count += count       

    # Print file name with count of "Unknown" and omitting the .csv from name
    if count != 0:
        print('\n,' + file[:-4] + ':' + str(count))


if total_count == 0:
    print('\nAll files are ready to go!')
```

Comment: Thank you for the revision, but I get an error that says:  "name 'total_count' is not defined",  but I get your logic.  If I don't use total_count but keep your formatting with the outside if statement and use just 'count', I do get a single print line of "All files are ready to go!" but I also get any files with the "Unknown" as well.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the line `total_count = 0`?